# Javascript classes Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token; Gender rendering

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a class gender that based on the user will render based on the user gender three different option;
his/her, him/her, he/she.

I tried to used classes but I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Her is my code:
in the variable gender is stored a dict with the ID of the user and his gender; so `{ 152: "M"}` for example

```
gender = data.gender
var Gender = class{

      constructor(val){
        this.val = val
      };
      gend = gender[val];
      if (gend === "M"){
        hisher(){
          return "his"
        };
        himher(){
          return "him"
        };
        heshe(){
          return "he"
        };
      } else {
        hisher(){
          return "her"
        };
        himher(){
          return "her"
        };
        heshe(){
          return "she"
        };
      };
    };
```

Comment: What is this `hisher(){`?

Comment: This looks more like typescript, not javascipt, is tagging correct?

Comment: WHat I am trying to achieve is to be able to create method based on a class ( like in python) where for example if var a = new Gender(val), that a.hisher would render his if the user is a men or her if the user is a girl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have step-by-step code (the `if`/`else` statement) that isn't in any method or a constructor. Your step-by-step code must be in a method or constructor. (Also: You don't put a `;` after the constructor declaration.)

You *could* define the class in each branch of that `if`/`else`, but instead I think I'd parameterize the class instead:

```
class Gender{
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.gender = gender[val];
    }
    hisher() {
        return this.gender === "M" ? "his" : "her";
    }
    himher() {
        return this.gender === "M" ? "him" : "her";
    }
    heshe() {
        return this.gender === "M" ? "he" : "she";
    }
}
```

or you could move the condition into the constructor

```
class Gender {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this._hisher = this.gender === "M" ? "his" : "her";
        this._himher = this.gender === "M" ? "him" : "her";
        this._heshe  = this.gender === "M" ? "he"  : "she";
        this.gender = gender[val];
    }
    hisher() {
        return this._hisher;
    }
    himher() {
        return this._himher;
    }
    heshe() {
        return this._heshe;
    }
}
```

but if you really want to define different classes, then:

```
let Gender;
if (gender[val] === "M") {
    Gender = {
        constructor(val) {
            this.val = val;
        }
        hisher() {
            return "his";
        }
        himher() {
            return "him";
        }
        heshe() {
            return "he";
        }
    };
} else {
    Gender = class {
        constructor(val) {
            this.val = val;
        }
        hisher() {
            return "her";
        }
        himher() {
            return "her";
        }
        heshe() {
            return "she";
        }
    };
}
```